# How to remove the decimal point from the result of an array

Tags: python

```
from array import array
scores = array('d')
scores.append(90)
scores.append(91)
print(scores)
print(scores[1])
```

How do we remove the decimal point from the result of an array?

Comment: Why do you need an `array` for this - in particular, one defined with `d` if you don't want doubles? `scores = [], scores.append(90), scores.append(91)` should be what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scores = array('d')` initializes an array of doubles (as denoted by `'d'`) rather than integers. If you want to hold an array of values without decimals construct an array this way you could write `array('i')`.

You might also want to take a look at [other data types that may fit your needs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html).

If you just want to print the values without the decimal you can cast them into integers when printing as such: `print(int(scores[1]))`

Comment: thanks for your help, I think I missed out the last parenthesis:|

Answer (score 0):

You can string format to 0 decimal points `print("{0:.0f}".format(scores[1]))`.

Answer (score 0):

So the value of the element '90' you stored while appending in the array is of data type **float**

You can eliminate decimal by converting the value to float while printing as follows

```
print(int(scores[1]))
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I think I missed out the last parenthesis:|

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use round() for eg round(arr[i],1)

Comment: thank you, it works, and there are many other methods to do that

Comment: It can also be used to round float numbers in python

Comment: Yes @arnavTaneja